# Trying to get SMTP mail server working for devise confirmable in rails app on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, actionmailer, production-environment, devise-confirmable

I have recently deployed to Heroku and everything seems to function okay. However, when I try to sign up with a new devise user, the confirmable module causes my app to crash. Most likely it's how I set up the action mailer and SMTP servers.

I'll post my code below.

`production.rb`:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'boiling-chamber-89366.herokuapp.com' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port => 587,
  :domain => "gmail.com",
  :user_name => ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
  :password => ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"],
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

`devise.rb`:

```
config.confirmation_keys = [:email]
```

What my `users` table looks like in `schema.rb`:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.boolean "admin", default: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

Heroku logs:

```
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445505+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionmailer-5.2.1/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:560:in `block in deliver_mail'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445503+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mail-2.7.0/lib/mail/message.rb:260:in `block in deliver'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445508+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445510+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445512+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionmailer-5.2.1/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:558:in `deliver_mail'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445522+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionmailer-5.2.1/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:114:in `block in deliver_now'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445514+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mail-2.7.0/lib/mail/message.rb:260:in `deliver'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445524+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionmailer-5.2.1/lib/action_mailer/rescuable.rb:17:in `handle_exceptions'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445525+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionmailer-5.2.1/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:113:in `deliver_now'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445529+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.5.0/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:121:in `send_confirmation_instructions'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445531+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.5.0/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:183:in `send_on_create_confirmation_instructions'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445532+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:426:in `block in make_lambda'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445506+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `block in instrument'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445527+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.5.0/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb:200:in `send_devise_notification'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445538+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:517:in `each'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445534+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:261:in `block in conditional'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445539+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:517:in `invoke_after'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445541+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:133:in `run_callbacks'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445536+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:517:in `block in invoke_after'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445547+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:816:in `_run_commit_callbacks'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445551+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:128:in `commit_records'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445555+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:223:in `block in commit_transaction'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445549+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:346:in `committed!'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445558+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:213:in `commit_transaction'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445556+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/ruby-2.3.5/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445560+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:252:in `block in within_new_transaction'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445562+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/ruby-2.3.5/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445564+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:236:in `within_new_transaction'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445569+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:385:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445567+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:212:in `transaction'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445565+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:254:in `transaction'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445571+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:310:in `block in save'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445573+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:325:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445574+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:309:in `save'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445579+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:44:in `save'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445581+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.5.0/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:19:in `create'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445582+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445586+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445584+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:194:in `process_action'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445587+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445591+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445589+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:132:in `run_callbacks'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445595+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:34:in `block in process_action'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445593+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445596+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `block in instrument'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445603+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445605+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445606+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `process_action'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445608+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:256:in `process_action'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445610+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `process_action'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445612+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:134:in `process'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445613+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionview-5.2.1/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:32:in `process'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445621+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:252:in `dispatch'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445615+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:191:in `dispatch'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445623+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:52:in `dispatch'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445626+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:18:in `block in <class:Constraints>'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445624+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:34:in `serve'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445628+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:48:in `serve'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445629+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:52:in `block in serve'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445631+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `each'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445633+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `serve'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445635+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:840:in `call'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445636+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/warden-1.2.7/lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445638+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/warden-1.2.7/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `catch'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445640+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/warden-1.2.7/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445642+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445644+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445645+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:38:in `call'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445647+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445649+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445650+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445652+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445654+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:670:in `call'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445656+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445662+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445664+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445673+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445665+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:61:in `call'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445675+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445679+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445680+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445677+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445684+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445682+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445685+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445687+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445688+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445690+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445692+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445694+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445695+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445699+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445701+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445697+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445702+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/server.rb:658:in `handle_request'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445704+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445706+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/server.rb:332:in `block in run'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.445707+00:00 app[web.1]: [1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:133:in `block in spawn_thread'
2018-09-14T17:43:33.450275+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users" host=boiling-chamber-89366.herokuapp.com request_id=1499438e-5bd8-4a70-b4ab-85fbeb7cafe1 fwd="71.239.123.112" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=433ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
2018-09-14T17:43:33.594196+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=boiling-chamber-89366.herokuapp.com request_id=dc35e8ef-67b0-48da-aa81-58570d67edf8 fwd="71.239.123.112" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=48 protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *strongly* urge you to use something other than Gmail for sending email from your application. Gmail is great for interactive use, but isn't designed for bulk use by applications. There are many services out there that are a better fit.

[Heroku agrees](https://help.heroku.com/CFG547YP/why-am-i-getting-errors-when-sending-email-with-gmail-via-smtp):

> ### Why am I getting errors when sending email with Gmail via SMTP?
>
> #### Issue
>
> Applications using Gmail to deliver email are failing with errors.
>
> #### Resolution
>
> Gmail have protections in place to avoid their service being used to deliver spam, however these are not published for security reasons. However we often see issues where customer applications attempt to use a Gmail account for email delivery which is subsequently blocked.
>
> To ensure reliable email delivery from apps running on Heroku, we recommend using one of the many email add-ons here: https://elements.heroku.com/addons Many of these have good free plans for low-medium volumes of email as well as excellent analytics and reporting features.

Comment: Thanks again Chris for encouraging me to look into other options. I switched from gmail to sendgrid-ruby and it works perfectly.

Comment: It definitely solved my problem but now I have a new problem. My MacBook pro crashed and wouldn't reload the disk image on startup. Oy. That's why you constantly push to github. I lost all of my work over the last day or two. Normally I'm religious about commits and pushes but I was caught.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Good luck with your system restore.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Yeah the hard drive took a dump. Guess it's time to get an SSD on this older MacBook.